# GDAL hillshade artifacts

Tags: gdal

I'm using gdal to create different kinds of layers, such as color reliefs and hillshades, and Mapnik to combine them into a single image to use as texture for the 3D dem model obtained from a single .hgt file.
Premising that I'm new to gdal, I'm facing some problem with the hillshade layer.
By using the gdal command:
`gdal_translate N44E007.hgt N44E007.tif`

I get the N44E007.tif file, which in IrfanView looks like this

[image: N44E007.tif in IrfanView]

With the following gdal command:
`gdaldem hillshade -of PNG .\tif\N44E007.tif .\hillshade_png\N44E007_hillshade.png`

The N44E007_hillshade.png file I get is the following

[image: N44E007_hillshade.png]

How can I prevent gdal from creating these artifacts in the hillshade .png?
I'm using Windows 7 and cmd.

**Update 1**
This is the image I get by replacing `gdal_translate N44E007.hgt N44E007.tif` with `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:32632 -r bilinear N44E006.hgt N44E006.tif`

[image: N44E007_reprojected_hillshade.png]
The problem is that the reprojected image is slightly rotated and stretched. How can I get a squared and straight image to use as texture for a 3d plane?

Comment: The artifacts might be a result of your input file since they clearly only appear in the valley / flat area. Maybe you can share the .hgt file with us. Also, this question might be a better fit over at the [GIS StackExchance](http://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxw8HXuQB4r6QjQxUGRxVWVPaEE/view?usp=sharing. I tried to post it to the GIS StackExchange but I don't have 5 reputation yet. Morover, I replaced `gdal_translate N44E007.hgt N44E007.tif` with `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:32632 -r bilinear N44E007.hgt N44E007.tif` and now it looks ok, without artifacts. The problem is that I need a "straight" version to use as a plane texture and the EPSG reprojection doesn't give me a square but something more like a trapezium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the artefacts in the first attempt is because the raster horizontal distance units are in degrees, and the vertical are in meters. You can use a [scale option](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html) to normalise horizontal and vertical distance units, e.g. try:

```
gdaldem hillshade -s 111120 -compute_edges -of PNG N44E007.hgt N44E007_hs.png
```

[image: N44E007_hs.png]

The second attempt (Update 1) reprojects to [WGS84 UTM zone 32](http://epsg.io/32632), which is a transverse Mercator projection centred on a meridian at 9°E, which is close to the SRTM raster, which is centred on 7.5°E. Since the two meridians are not the same, it is expected the raster to be rotated. And it is stretched since the true distance of degrees are not equal in N-S and E-W directions, except at the equator.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much! Is it possibile to know how you computed the scale factor for the gdaldem command?

Comment: It was actually on the help page that I linked on, but it is derived from the equatorial circumference of 40075016.68 m / 360° = 111319.49 m/°. Interestingly, this is close but different that the recommended one, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @MikeT  because the Earth is ellipsoidal and your formula is for a perfect sphere. 111319.49 will likely work well because NA/Europe is about half way up the surface and in between the ellipse extremes.